# Use MVC to manage grid column events

Tags: extjs, combobox, grid

I have a grid with some columns(combobox columns) which I need to manage their change events. I want to do it from a controller. The goal is to send the server the selected combo id when i need to insert or update the row and update the other columns depending of the value of this selected combo. Could you give me an example how I much do this?

I have 2 hidden columns which must be updated when the Combo Empresa and Camion changes with the id.

This is my grid def:

```
{
                        xtype: 'gridpanel',
                        id: 'grdListaFichaEmbarques',
                        minWidth: 1024,
                        autoScroll: true,
                        title: 'Listado de Fichas',
                        store: 'ListaFichasTransporte',
                        plugins: [
                            Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
                                pluginId: 'ListaFEPlugin'
                            })
                        ],
                        columns: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'numbercolumn',
                                dataIndex: 'NumEmbarque',
                                text: 'NumEmbarque'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                dataIndex: 'Empresa',
                                text: 'Empresa',
                                editor: {
                                    xtype: 'combobox',
                                    allowBlank: false,
                                    displayField: 'Nombre',
                                    hiddenName: 'Id',
                                    store: 'ListaEmpresa',
                                    valueField: 'Id'
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                dataIndex: 'Contacto',
                                text: 'Contacto'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                dataIndex: 'Celular',
                                text: 'Celular'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                dataIndex: 'Placa1',
                                text: 'Placa1',
                                editor: {
                                    xtype: 'combobox',
                                    allowBlank: false,
                                    displayField: 'Placa1',
                                    store: 'ListaCamiones',
                                    valueField: 'Id'
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                dataIndex: 'Placa2',
                                text: 'Placa2'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                dataIndex: 'Capacidad',
                                text: 'Capacidad'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                dataIndex: 'Chofer',
                                text: 'Chofer'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                dataIndex: 'Nextel',
                                text: 'Nextel'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                dataIndex: 'CelularPeru',
                                text: 'CelularPeru'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                dataIndex: 'CelularEcuador',
                                text: 'CelularEcuador'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                dataIndex: 'Termoregistro1',
                                text: 'Termoregistro1'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                dataIndex: 'Termoregistro2',
                                text: 'Termoregistro2'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                dataIndex: 'PuntoRecojo',
                                text: 'PuntoRecojo',
                                editor: {
                                    xtype: 'combobox',
                                    displayField: 'Nombre',
                                    store: 'ListaOrigenDestino',
                                    valueField: 'Id'
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'datecolumn',
                                dataIndex: 'FechaHoraLlegadaOrigen',
                                text: 'FechaHoraLlegadaOrigen',
                                editor: {
                                    xtype: 'datefield',
                                    format: 'd/m/Y h:i:s',
                                    submitFormat: 'd/m/Y h:i:s'
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'datecolumn',
                                dataIndex: 'FechaHoraDespachoOrigen',
                                text: 'FechaHoraDespachoOrigen',
                                editor: {
                                    xtype: 'datefield',
                                    format: 'd/m/Y h:i:s',
                                    submitFormat: 'd/m/Y h:i:s'
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'datecolumn',
                                dataIndex: 'FechaHoraLlegadaTumbes',
                                text: 'FechaHoraLlegadaTumbes',
                                editor: {
                                    xtype: 'datefield',
                                    format: 'd/m/Y h:i:s',
                                    submitFormat: 'd/m/Y h:i:s'
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                dataIndex: 'PuntoLlegadaEcuador',
                                text: 'PuntoLlegadaEcuador',
                                editor: {
                                    xtype: 'combobox',
                                    displayField: 'Nombre',
                                    store: 'ListaOrigenDestino',
                                    valueField: 'Id'
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'datecolumn',
                                dataIndex: 'FechaHoraLLegadaDestinoEcuador',
                                text: 'FechaHoraLLegadaDestinoEcuador',
                                editor: {
                                    xtype: 'datefield',
                                    format: 'd/m/Y h:i:s',
                                    submitFormat: 'd/m/Y h:i:s'
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'numbercolumn',
                                hidden: true,
                                dataIndex: 'IdEmpresa',
                                text: 'IdEmpresa'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'numbercolumn',
                                hidden: true,
                                dataIndex: 'IdCamion',
                                text: 'IdCamion'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
```

This is my Controller:

```
Ext.define('Fplweb2.controller.FichaEmbarque', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

refs: [
    {
        ref: 'GrillaFE',
        selector: 'grid[id=grdListaFichaEmbarques]',
        xtype: 'Ext.grid.Panel'
    }
],

onButtonClick: function(button, e, eOpts) {
    this.save();


},

onComboboxSelect: function(combo, records, eOpts) {
    var grid = this.getGrillaFE();
    var store = grid.getStore();

    //HERE I WAS TRYING TO UPDATE THE COLUMNS
    if( grid.getSelectionModel().hasSelection() )
    {
        var row = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
        var srow;
        for(var i=0; i<store.count(); i++)
        {
            srow = store.getAt(i);
            if(srow.get('NumEmbarque') == row[0].data.NumEmbarque)
            {
                console.log("ASIGNARA");
                srow.IdEmpresa = records[0].data.Id;
                srow.Contacto  = records[0].data.Contacto;
                srow.Celular   = records[0].data.Celular;
            }

        }
    }

},

init: function(application) {
    this.listen({
        controller: {},
        component: {
            'grid[xtype=gridpanel]': {
                edit: this.save,
                canceledit: this.cancel
        }
    });

    this.control({
        "button[id=btnFichaEmbarqueAgregar]": {
            click: this.onButtonClick
        },
        "combobox[id=cmbGrdListaFichaEmbarquesEmpresa]": {
            select: this.onComboboxSelect
        }
    });
},

save: function() {
    var fechaact = new Date();

    var grid = this.getGrillaFE();
    var plugin = grid.editingPlugin;
    var store = grid.getStore();

    //SET THE FIRTS COMBO VALUE
    //Combo Lista Empresas
    var lestore =  Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('ListaEmpresa').getAt(0).get('Nombre');
    //Combo Lista Origen - Destino
    var odstore =  Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('ListaOrigenDestino').getAt(0).get('Nombre');
    //Combo Lista Camiones
    var lcstore =  Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('ListaCamiones').getAt(0).get('Placa1');

    plugin.cancelEdit();

    var r = Ext.create('Fplweb2.model.ListaFichasTransporte', {
        NumEmbarque: store.getCount() + 1,
        Empresa: lestore,
        Contacto: 'Nuevo Contacto',
        Celular: '999999999',
        Placa1: lcstore,
        Placa2: '',
        Capacidad: '',
        Chofer: 'Nuevo Chofer',
        Nextel: '999999999',
        CelularPeru: '999999999',
        CelularEcuador: '999999999',
        Termoregistro1: '',
        Termoregistro2: '',
        PuntoRecojo: odstore,
        FHTranspPuntoRecojo: fechaact,
        FHDespaPuntoRecojo: fechaact,
        FHLlegadaTumbes: fechaact,
        PuntoLlegadaEcuador: odstore,
        FHLlegadaPuntoEcuador: fechaact
    });


    store.insert(0, r);
    plugin.startEdit(0, 0);
    store.sync();

},

cancel: function(editor, context, eOpts) {

    console.log("cancelo");
    var grid = this.getGrillaFE();
    var plugin = grid.editingPlugin;
    var store = grid.getStore();
    plugin.cancelEdit();
    store.removeAt(0);

    if( context.record.phantom ) {
        context.store.remove( context.record );
    }
}
```

});

I want to do this FROM a controller.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to catch the [`edit`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.Editing-event-edit) event of the grid (added by the editing plugin):

```
listeners: {
    edit: function(editor, e) {
        if (e.field === 'Empresa') {
            // do a trip to the server if needed

            // or update your column locally
            e.record.set('IdCamion', e.value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had added in the rowediting edit, and i put a console.log() to see when pass this event, but the console never shows nothing. How do i do this from a controller?